Difference between である and にある
Here is a sentence I saw today on Duolingo:

世界の人口は増加傾向にある。

Translation: "The world population is on an upward trend."
Why is にある used here instead of である? I thought that expression was only used to mean where something is or takes place. For instance:

両国は戦争状態にあります。

Translation: "The two countries are in a state of war."
This is a usage I understand, since に refers to the situation in which both countries are. However, though I've previously come across a few にある usages such as the first example, I don't really understand why that's chosen over である.

増加傾向 should be 増加の傾向?

That is not the case in the source where I took it from, I'm afraid.

Location does not need to be physical. "State of war" and "state/tendency/trend of increase/growth" are similarly abstract "locations".

Understood. I wonder if this usage of the に particle is common. In my grammar studies, I haven't yet come across an explanation for that. Maybe there isn't one because I asked a question that, looking back now, is too trivial.

Wouldn't it be more natural to say 状態になっている?  Instead of 状態にある?

である＝だ.  You cannot use である in sentences where you not saying something like A=B, AはBである。
